# I want to use google Firebase Authentication in my xamarin project. with anonymous authentication and google authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I had created project in console.firebase.google.com and have Xamarin.forms Application.

Now i want to provide default login with anonymous authentication and then if he/she want to login with google then it can login from that.

I am sorry to say but I am not clear that how i can do it.
If anybody can help me in this, then I will be thankful to him.

I refer some well known links for it as given below.

1. https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet
2. https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin

Comment: Anyone can please in this as I am still stuck here.

Comment: do you mean you can use Facebook, Twitter, google or Instagram account for your app login? if thats the case then you need to use Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator